# Can I use a Windows 8 Professional licence to activate Windows Enterprise edition?

Tags: windows-8

Can I use the licence I purchased for Windows 8 Professional to activate Windows 8 Enterprise Edition (which has a 90 days expiration period)?

I have a very slow Internet connection  and it is taking ages to download Windows 8 Professional through the Upgrade Assistant. However I have the .iso for Windows 8 Enterprise, so I want to install it and save time.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. This cannot be done. You also cannot "purchase" the evaluation of Windows 8 Enterprise.   The installation of Windows 8 Enterprise requires an installation media.

Comment: Oh well. Okay looks like I have to download for another 10 hours. Sigh.
Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Reinstalling everything from scratch. Sigh. Thanks for nice evaluation, Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way (even by illegal hacks) to remove the 90 days expiration in the Enterprise demo.
Also you can't install it with a wrong key (Pro has a different key)

Comment: actually you can use the "slmgr /rearm" command to extend the trial period legally. It can only be used once, so [you get a total of 180 days legally](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/0b85757a-1b4c-48ad-a7bd-ef123d732701)

Comment: I read that it wouldn't work anymore? Maybe I remember wrong

Comment: From what I have read, it works only once, not sure but I think you have to wait until the current trial ends, then rearm.

Answer (score 0):

Open an elevated command prompt, type in:

> slmgr /rearm

this will [extend the evaluation period another 90 days](http://www.technize.net/download-windows-8-enterprise-rtm-with-180-day-activation/?ModPagespeed=noscript), it can only be done once and is legal.